# WMIC to check connectivity from remote machines

Tags: networking, wmic

I have over 5,000 servers that require to be validated for connectivity with logging server. There is no automation tool or PowerShell Remoting available & **currently an engineer has to manually login (RDP - Remote Desktop) to each server and do a TELNET / FTP to verify the connectivity**.

Since WMIC is available, I was hoping to get help with using WMIC to get the output.

Here is the flow:

```
Administration workstation --> WMIC --> Server1, Server2, ServerN --> Start Telnet/FTP --> Try connecting to logging server on a particular port --> Output back on Administration workstation.
```

I have tried the following but I am only getting output of process being created as opposed to output from Telnet/FTP.

```
WMIC /node:computer1,computer2 /user:domain\userid PROCESS call create "telnet.exe remoteIP port > C:\output.txt"
```

I would kindly request help of the following:

1. Is there a second way to achieve connectivity testing details? Please keep in mind, there is no assistance from the network/network-security teams.
2. How to do this via WMIC?

Comment: How about [PsExec](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/psexec)?

Comment: Information security has stopped PsExec :(